# How to initialize a vue property with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

In this code like in line 19 i want to pass `document.body.getElementById('calculationid').value` to a vue variable (`calcvalue`) but it does not work, so how i can solve it or is there any other solutions to get the input tag value  .

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
 
    <input type="text" v-model="calcoperation" id="calculationid"  >

  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
  name:"home",
  data(){
    return{
     var calcvalue : document.body.getElementById('calculationid').value ,
      title: "",
      valuecalc: "",
      calcoperation: "" 
     // valuecalc: calcoperation
    };
  },
  methods:{
    //To contact the input field text with the button pressed
    contterms(str){
      var temp = "" + str  
      
      this.calcoperation = this.calcoperation + temp
    }
  }, 
  mounted(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8085")
      .then(response =>{
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(data =>{
        this.title=data;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manipulate the DOM in that way, you could declare `calcvalue`  as an empty variable then update it by watching `calcoperation` or by defining it as computed property :

```
data(){
    return{
     calcvalue : "" ,
      title: "",
      valuecalc: "",
      calcoperation: "" 
     // valuecalc: calcoperation
    }
},
watch:{
   calcoperation(newVal,oldVal){
    this.calcvalue=newVal
   }

}
```

Comment: By this you make the v-model set to this watcher ?? @Boussadjra

Comment: your input is still bound to `calcoperation` like `<input type="text" v-model="calcoperation" id="calculationid"  >`, the watcher just looks to the changes and does the appropriate logic like `this.calcvalue=newVal`

Comment: So can i set the value attribute in the input tag to calcvalue @Boussadjra

Comment: no, that will raise an error because you've already defined the `v-model`

Comment: sorry, is there a way to set it ? @ Boussadjra Brahim

Comment: the input is already bound to `calcoperation` and you could modify `calcvalue` as i suggested, could explain more your real need

Comment: I want to change calcoperation, then display that changes in the input tag @Boussadjra Brahim

Comment: `calcoperation` is two-way bound to the input, any change in the input will affect `calcoperation` and vice-versa